# Start http, mysql, ftp and cronjobs at boot on EC2 running Linux?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cron

Is there a script that can be run at launch to start all these? If so, where do I put it?

If not, is there a way to do it via the management console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Just Works if you install these from packages. An init script will be placed in `/etc/init.d` and they will be started on boot.

for example installing apache with:

> `sudo apt-get install apache2`

will result in the file `/etc/init.d/apache2` being installed and the appropriate links set up to ensure the script gets called on system startup and shutdown.

You can edit the crontab with the command:

> `crontab -e`

The cron daemon is automatically started at boot time and will run these commands according to the times you specify.